# Trying to compare dates differences that are over a month apart

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am doing some work in Excel, and need to compare two dates columns. I understand the =IF(date1>date2,"Y","N") function, but I ideally would like the function to return yes only if the dates occur in a different month.

For example, date1 = 03/01/2017 and date2 = 03/27/2017 would return N because same month, same year. But if date1 = 03/05/2017 and date2 = 04/02/2017, it would return Y since different dates different months.

So I'm not looking for a 30 day difference between dates, I'm literally looking for the number of the month being different.

Is there an easy enough way to do this, that would be supreme. I am sure that it will probably require a macro in VBA, but who knows? Excel continually amazes me with its robustness and usability.

Comment: `text(date1, "mmyyyy")<>text(date2, "mmyyyy")`

Answer (score 3):

Excel has some useful functions to break dates up into their individual components.  In this case you are going to want to use the Month() and Year() functions; which respectively return the month and a the year of a date.

This formula checks to see if the month and the year line up and gives a Y if they do and an N if they don't:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(date1)=MONTH(date2),YEAR(date1)=YEAR(date2)),"Y","N")
```

If you are looking for the number of months difference you can modify the formula above like this:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(date1)=MONTH(date2),YEAR(date1)=YEAR(date2)),0,Month(date1)-Month(date2)+(12*(year(date1)-year(date2)))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Create a string text for each date and compare the strings.

```
=CHOOSE((TEXT(A2, "mmyyyy")<>TEXT(B2, "mmyyyy"))+1, "N", "Y")
```

[image]